# Combine - Assigning publisher value

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm sorry if this is a basic question but I'm still getting to grips with Combine.

I have a publisher that is linked to changes in CoreData.

I am trying to subscribe to those changes in my ViewModel using :

```
CDPublisher(
        request: Book.fetchAllBooks(),
        context: PersistentStore.shared.context
    )
    .map { $0 }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { [weak self] newBooks in
        self?.books = newBooks // Error here
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

I want to assign the new array of books `newBooks` to an `@Published` array called `books` of type `[Book]`.

However I get this error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Subscribers.Completion<CDPublisher.Failure>' (aka 'Subscribers.Completion') to type '[Book]'

I believe the problem stems from my `.map`. I added it because without it I got this error:

> Referencing instance method 'sink(receiveValue:)' on 'Publisher' requires the types 'CDPublisher.Failure' (aka 'Error') and 'Never' be equivalent

FYI the publisher I'm using is taken from: https://betterprogramming.pub/combine-publishers-and-core-data-424b68fe9473

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the Output and Failure types of CDPublisher? It's important because there are two versions of sink. One has two closure arguments `sink(receiveCompletion:receiveValue:)` and the other just `sink(receiveValue:)`. You are trying to use the second, but you can only do so if the Failure type is Never. Try removing the .map and use the first type of sink, handling any failure that might be published.

Comment: To clarify, technically failure's (usually Error type) aren't published. They just cause the publisher to complete with failure set.

Comment: Many thanks @CenkBilgen. The failure type was Error and so I removed the map and added `sink(receiveCompletion:receiveValue:)`. Worked as expected after this change.